# Configuring android to work on appcelerator titanium

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am running windows 7, and am trying to configure android to work in titanium...

I have installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of Java... (android didn't seem to work with the 64 bit version)...

When you go to configure android from within titanium I am getting the following error...

Items required:
•Add-Ons Google APIs 7, Google APIs 8

When you then click install or update Android, Android SDK manager opens and selects what I need to install... I click accept and it downloads and installs...

However once that completes, I still have the same error when going back to titanium...
It should not be this hard... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with the 64bit version. Have you tried uninstalling the 64bit versions of Java?

Also, have you run Android to update all the libraires?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but in case anyone googles it like I have, this is what helped me:

- make sure to install Google APIs at least for the latest Android SDK that you have installed
- **make sure to have Android 2.3.x installed**. This is critical, Titanium Studio somehow couldn't link to my Android SDK (set outside titanium folder) even though I had half a dozen higher than 2.3 SDKs installed
- restart Titanium Studio

Further more, in case this doesn't help, try clean-starting Titanium Studio, like so:

- close Titanium Studio
- go to your Titanium Studio installation folder (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Titanium Studio")
- open TitaniumStudio.ini
- copy these two lines at the beginning of the file:

> ```
> -clean
> true
> ```

- save file and start Titanium Studio.

After succesfull operation you can remove those two lines from .ini file as they are not needed.